# Control reaches end of non-void function undefined behavoir

Tags: c++, enums, return, switch-statement, undefined-behavior

For this code:

```
enum class Colors { Red, Green, Blue };

int fun(Colors color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
        case Colors::Red: return 0;
        case Colors::Blue: return 1;
        case Colors::Green: return 2;
    }
}
```

My compiler threw this error at me:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

I know it is undefined behavior to have no return statement in a function, but is it undefined behavior to not have a return statement for all control paths? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "no return statement in a function" is just a special case of "not have a return statement for all control paths"...

Comment: In short, yes, it's UB.

Comment: It's only UB if it happens. If your switch variable can never have an unhandled value, the function doesn't flow off the end, so it's not UB.

Comment: `g++` gurns about this, but interestingly, `clang++` does not. IMHO there should always be an option for users who use their own functions properly and have no interest in being warned that some imaginary caller could cast an out-of-range value into an `enum class` and pass it in. Assuming proper `enum class` usage, this `switch` will always hit a valid `case`, and the end of the function won't be flowed off, meaning no UB is involved. Why does `g++` insist that I must artificially insert a `default:` or `return` or `abort()` just to avoid being shouted at about this?

Comment: Clang, if you handle all your `enum` (including non-`class`) cases, is silent, and if you don't - of course you get the `Wswitch` message, _but_ then `warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`. So Clang's `Wreturn-type` only fires in missing cases and even then says "**may** reach" (i.e. thanks to a stupid/malicious caller), not _reaches_. GCC could do one better by defaulting to warning about such callers - but allowing the warning to be disabled by competent ones. But it seems they don't want to be that nuanced ;-) https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53479

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the return value of `fun` is not `void`, so, yes, it's undefined behavior.

> C++11 6.6.3 The `return` statement
>
> [...]  Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Comment: It's only UB if it happens. If the switch variable can never have an unhandled value, the function doesn't flow off the end, so it's not UB.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that you have called your `fun` function with incorrect value, not Red, Blue or Green. You can change your code to

```
int fun(Colors color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
        case Colors::Red: return 0;
        case Colors::Blue: return 1;
        case Colors::Green: return 2;
        default: return -1; // Unknown color here!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's okay to not have a `return` statement in a function, if it returns `void`. However, for a function *not* returning `void` it's always undefined behavior to not have a valid return value from any execution path.

So in your case, you need a `return` with a value after the `switch`.

Note that you don't need a `default` case if you list all the possible cases in the `switch` statement.

Comment: The UB only exists if the non-`return`ing path is taken. It shouldn't be with an `enum class`, and we should be allowed to tell the compiler to shut up and assume we don't use casting acrobatics to pass in an invalid value. Anyway, about your claim that a default isn't needed if all the `case`s are listed, then `g++` disagrees and still prints its incessant, inapplicable warning: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ac7406bda6c430